# Unit vector in polar coordinate system

Tags: coordinate-systems, vectors

Why does the unit vector in polar coordinates change with time when an objects position is changed?

Comment: Have you drawn a diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Intuitively, because the polar coordinate directions are relative. Whatever point I'm at, $\hat{r}$ points from *that* point, away from the origin. $\hat{r}$ (or $\theta$) vs $\hat{x}$ are not entirely dissimilar to "your left" vs "north". Which direction "left" is changes as you move around whereas north stays the same.

Comment: Thanks mate bRost03